# AWS-CDK Example of CloudWatch Alarm with Anomaly detection

Tags: python, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

Can someone provide a generic example of AWS Cloudwatch Alarm based on Anomaly Detection of a metric built with AWS CDK in Python3?

I have tried mapping [aws cloudformation example of it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloudwatch-anomalydetector.html) to `aws_cdk.aws_cloudwatch.Alarm` and `aws_cdk.aws_cloudwatch.CfnAlarm` with little to no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually managed to make anomaly detection work with CfnAlarm

```
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_sns as sns,
    aws_cloudwatch as cw,
    core
)

anomaly_detector = cw.CfnAnomalyDetector(
    self, "AnomalyDetector",
    metric_name="my_metric",
    namespace="my_namespace",
    stat="Sum"
)

slack_topic = sns.Topic(self, "AnomalySns",
                        display_name="anomaly-sns",
                        topic_name="anomaly-sns"
                        )

anomaly_cfnalarm = cw.CfnAlarm(self, "AnomalyAlarm",
                               actions_enabled=True,
                               alarm_actions=[slack_topic.topic_arn],
                               alarm_description="<..>",
                               alarm_name="AnomalyAlarm",
                               comparison_operator="LessThanLowerOrGreaterThanUpperThreshold",
                               datapoints_to_alarm=1,
                               evaluation_periods=1,
                               insufficient_data_actions=[slack_topic.topic_arn],
                               metrics=[
                                   cw.CfnAlarm.MetricDataQueryProperty(
                                       expression="ANOMALY_DETECTION_BAND(m1, 2)",
                                       id="ad1"
                                   ),
                                   cw.CfnAlarm.MetricDataQueryProperty(
                                       id="m1",
                                       metric_stat=cw.CfnAlarm.MetricStatProperty(
                                           metric=cw.CfnAlarm.MetricProperty(
                                               metric_name=anomaly_detector.metric_name,
                                               namespace=anomaly_detector.namespace
                                           ),
                                           period=core.Duration.minutes(5).to_seconds(),
                                           stat="Sum"
                                       )
                                   )
                               ],
                               ok_actions=[slack_topic.topic_arn],
                               threshold_metric_id="ad1",
                               treat_missing_data="breaching"
                               )
```

This is partially based on AWS Docs CloudFormation example of Cloudwatch Anomaly Alarm https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-alarm.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no high level constructor for AbnormalDetector in current CDK(v1.27.0).

Pls directly use low level class [CfnAnomalyDetector](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-cloudwatch.CfnAnomalyDetector.html).

There is an [example usage of AbnormalDetector with Alarm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-alarm.html#aws-properties-cw-alarm--examples) in CloudFormation doc. Use CDK low level `Cfn*` classes to create corresponding CFN configuration.

Comment: I do not think you understood the question. I am able to create CfnAnomalyDetector no problem. What I am unable to do is to create either Alarm or CfnAlarm that would trigger when detector detects an anomaly.